# How to call standard C library from Swift?

Tags: c, macos, swift

I want to use C libraries such as stdio.h, stdlib.h, etc. in my swift application. But I can't import . How can I do?

```
import <stdio.h> // BAD
#include <stdio.h> // BAD
#import <stdio.h> // BAD
import Foundation // cannot use printf etc.
```

Comment: Why? What functions to you want to use? Why do you want to use them instead of the standard Swift functions? What is the problem you are trying to solve by using C-library functions?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Please do not 'question the question', your comment implies "You shouldn't want to do this" which is annoying for the asker and for other readers.  Wing has a straightforward requirement around Swift/C interoperability which is valid now and even more relevant as soon as Swift goes Open Source in 2015.  Honestly your kind of comment is the most annoying part of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ChrisHatton Learning the rationale, and what the actual problem is, always helps. There might be better solutions than what the OP is asking about. Related reading: [What is the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Create a Bridging Header**

- Create an Obj-C header file
- Add the import statements
- Go to your projects build settings
- Find the ***Objective-C Bridging Header*** setting.
- Set it to the path/of/your/file
- The files you've imported into the header, will then be able to be used In all Swift files.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Answer (score 5):

To import C functions in pure Swift on the OS-X platform use:

```
import Darwin
```

This can be seen as one of the sub-imports inside Foundation.swift, but importing it individually avoids potentially unnecessary processing of Cocoa and other iOS/OSX framework modules.

NeilJaff's answer works because it causes Foundation and all submodules to be imported, but `import Darwin` is more targeted.